# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fulfillmentMessages' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to integrate Dialogflow to React Native and I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClBC93WPkmw) tutorial

However, I am encountering this error.

Below is my handleGoogleResponse that causes the error

```
handleGoogleResponse(result) {
    let text = result.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0]; //error
    this.sendBotResponse(text);
  }
```

I hope you could help me with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Try printing the content of `result` by doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` so you can see a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

its say that the queryResult is undefined,
check if you configured firebase currectly.

show intire code